# How to return large data from JsonResult object in MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, jqwidget

I have a requirement where I have to return 218034 records in a JSONRESULT object. This is used to bind to a datatable in jqwidgets. When I return around 5000 records it works fine but when I try to retrieve around  218034, I get a message on the datatable as "No data to display."

My Code in the Controller page:

```
    public JsonResult GetProducts()
        {
            var dbResult = db.Products.ToList();
            var products = (from product in dbResult
                            select new
                            {
                                product.ProductID,
                                product.ProductDesc,
                                product.ProductNumber                                
                            });
            return Json(products, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

My Code in the View:

```
@{
     ViewBag.Title = "jQWidgets DataTable";
 }
@section scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // prepare the data
            var source =
            {
                dataType: "json",
                dataFields: [
                    { name: 'ProductDesc', type: 'string' },
                    { name: 'ProductNumber', type: 'string' },

                ],
            id: 'ProductID',
            url: '/Product/GetProducts'
        };
            var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);
            // create Tree Grid
            $("#dataTable").jqxDataTable(
            {
                width: 1000,
                source: dataAdapter,
                theme: 'shinyblack',
                pageSize: 10,
                sortable: true,
                filterable: true,
                pageable: true,
                columns: [
                  { text: 'Product', dataField: 'ProductDesc', width: 200 },
                  { text: 'Product Number', dataField: 'ProductNumber',     width: 200 },

                ]
            });
        });
    </script>
}
<div id="dataTable"></div>
```

Can anyone please suggest what would be the best approach to show the large data. I am using MVC, jqwidgets.

Comment: I would suggest paging

Comment: 218000 records is unusable by anyone. Apply filtering/paging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be the problem is that you've exceeded the MaxJsonLength. There's a help topic about that [asp.net-largejsonresult](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/asp.net-integration/asp.net-largejsonresult.htm)